# when used Dictionary How can I get the value if it non nullable value type

Tags: c#

when used Dictionary

How can I get the value if it non nullable value type
this code

```
            Dictionary<string, object> DictionaryValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            RSAParameters publicKey = Storage.Read(_Path + @"\" + "Key.Public");
            DictionaryValues["publicKey"] = publicKey;


            RSAParameters publicKey2 = new RSAParameters();
            if (DictionaryValues.TryGetValue("publicKey", out object obj))
            {
                publicKey2 = obj as RSAParameters;
                
            }
```

I'm getting an error the as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type RSAParameters is anon nullable

How can I get the value  publicKey from inside the dictionary
Please help and thank you everyone

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0077

Comment: "***12.11.12 The as operator*** *The as operator is used to explicitly convert a value to a given reference type or nullable value type. Unlike
a cast expression (§12.8.7), the as operator never throws an exception. Instead, if the indicated conversion
is not possible, the resulting value is null.
In an operation of the form E as T, E shall be an expression and T shall be a reference type, a type
parameter known to be a reference type, or a nullable value type.*"

Comment: Some more reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast

Comment: Can you explain why the value of the dictionary is `object` not the expected type?

Comment: @PeterDuniho and a lot of others. Not really sure why this was reopped (especially given the lack of information in the given answer)

Comment: @TheGeneral: it was reopened because the person who posted an answer instead of voting to close as they should have, has the C# gold badge and reopened the question single-handedly (I guess as a way of protecting their inappropriately-posted answer). But another gold badge user, or three users of any persuasion, can reclose it again just as it should be.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - you are right but at first read of the dupe I missed the sane answer in the mess of `bool?` and DataReader solutions. Turns out the top answer does contain the same solution, you just have to look very hard. So this might have been a wrong reopening, I still think it has some value.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: _"this might have been a wrong reopening, I still think it has some value"_ -- if you feel that you have something new to contribute with respect to exiting answers for a duplicate question, the correct action is to post your answer with the already-existing question, rather than to the duplicate question, and to vote-to-close as a duplicate the duplicate (or preferably, leave it closed when it's been closed appropriately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//publicKey2 = obj as RSAParameters;
  publicKey2 = (RSAParameters)obj;
```

Comment: If you're not certain `obj` is of the right type, you can still test it with the `is` operator (`if (obj is RSAParameters) {...}`). But only do this if there's something meaningful you can do if it's the wrong type.

Comment: Or `as RSAParameters?`.